# Creating segue between views in swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

Currently making an app in swift where all elements are added programatically. how can i add segue programmatically for the action of a given button to switch from one view to the next?

Comment: Try this https://coderwall.com/p/-yka_q/create-and-perform-a-storyboard-segue-programatically

Comment: @RajeshkumarR - I see you attempted to edit this question to mark it as an iOS question. While it's likely an iOS question, it's not necessarily so. We should ask Ajp before making an edit like that...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating segues programmatically, you can use this inside button action to navigate to another view controller.

```
let viewController = MyViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: This of course assumes Ajp is using a navigation controller. If not, you might [`present(_:​animated:​completion:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) (or [`show(_:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621377-show)  or [`show​Detail​View​Controller(_:​sender:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621432-showdetailviewcontroller) or ...).

Answer (score 0):

You can push to your next viewcontroller without using segue as well like.

```
  @IBAction func btnClickNextVC(_ sender: Any) {

        let objSecondVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as? ViewController2
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objSecondVc!, animated: true)
        //or you can use
        present(objSecondVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Note: Don't forget to take `navigationcontroller` in storyboard.
and give storyboard identifier of your viewcontroller same as you pass here in the code `withidentifier`.